# Correctness of an Approximation involving the Log-Normal Distribution using Taylor (Maclaurin) Series

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, taylor-expansion, approximation

## Question

I am looking to find a simplification of the expression below. There seems to be a mistake in my attempt (steps shown below) using the Taylor (Maclaurin) series.

Could someone please verify if this approach is correct / provide additional pointers / alternative solutions?

## Expression for Approximation

$$
\beta\left(x\right) = \left[x-\int_{0}^{x}\left[\frac{\Phi\left(\frac{lny-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{lnx-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}\right]^{M-1}dy\right]
$$

Here, $\Phi(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{u}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt$
, the standard normal cumulative distribution and $X=e^{W}$where, $W\sim N\left(\mu,\sigma\right)$. $M$ is a non-zero positive integer. $\beta(x)=0$, when $x=0$

## Steps Tried

\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta\left(x\right) & = & \left[x-\frac{\int_{0}^{x}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{lny-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^{M-1}dy}{\left[\Phi\left(\frac{lnx-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^{M-1}}\right]\\
 & = & \left[x-\frac{\left\{ \int_{0}^{x}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\left(\frac{lny-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt\right]^{M-1}dy\right\} }{\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\left(\frac{lnx-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt\right]^{M-1}}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Let,
\begin{eqnarray*}
h\left(y\right) & = & \left[\int_{-\infty}^{\left(\frac{lny-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt\right]^{M-1}\\
j\left(y\right) & = & \int h\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
We then have,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta\left(x\right) & = & \left[x-\frac{\left\{ \int_{0}^{x}h\left(y\right)dy\right\} }{h\left(x\right)}\right]\\
 & = & \left[x-\frac{\left|j\left(y\right)\right|_{0}^{x}}{h\left(x\right)}\right]=\left[x-\left\{ \frac{j\left(x\right)-j\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right\} \right]\\
 & \approx & \left[x-\frac{j'\left(0\right)x}{h\left(x\right)}\right]\;\left\{ \because j\left(x\right)-j\left(0\right)\simeq j'\left(0\right)x\;,\quad Maclaurin\; Series\right\} \\
 & = & \left[x-\frac{h\left(0\right)x}{h\left(x\right)}\right]=x\left[1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Rightarrow\beta\left(x\right) & = & x\;\left[\;\because h\left(0\right)=\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\left(\frac{ln0-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt\right]^{M-1}=\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt\right]^{M-1}=0\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
We could include additional terms, for greater precision, using the
subsequent terms of the Maclaurin series, as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta\left(x\right) & \approx & x\left[1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{x}{2}\frac{h'\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right]\;\left\{ \because j\left(x\right)-j\left(0\right)\simeq j'\left(0\right)x+\frac{j''\left(0\right)x^{2}}{2!}\right\} \\
\beta\left(x\right) & = & x\left[1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{2}\left\{ 1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right\} \right]\;\left\{ \because\frac{h\left(x\right)-h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\simeq\frac{h'\left(0\right)x}{h\left(x\right)}\right\} \\
\Rightarrow\beta\left(x\right) & = & \frac{x}{2}\;\left[\;\because h\left(0\right)=0\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta\left(x\right) & \approx & x\left[1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{x}{2}\frac{h'\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{x^{2}}{6}\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right]\\
 &  & \;\left\{ \because j\left(x\right)-j\left(0\right)\simeq j'\left(0\right)x+\frac{j''\left(0\right)x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{j'''\left(0\right)x^{3}}{3!}\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta\left(x\right) & \approx & x\left[1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{x}{2}\frac{h'\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{3}\left\{ 1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-x\frac{h'\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right\} \right]\\
 &  & \;\left\{ \because\frac{h\left(x\right)-h\left(0\right)-h'\left(0\right)x}{h\left(x\right)}\simeq\frac{1}{2}\frac{h''\left(0\right)x^{2}}{h\left(x\right)}\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta\left(x\right) & \approx & x\left[1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{x}{2}\frac{h'\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}+\frac{x}{3}\frac{h'\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right]\\
 & = & x\left[\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{6}\left\{ 1-\frac{h\left(0\right)}{h\left(x\right)}\right\} \right]\\
\Rightarrow\beta\left(x\right) & = & \frac{x}{2}\;\left[\;\because h\left(0\right)=0\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

## Reason for Concern

I checked this for correctness using this website: http://www.integral-calculator.com and [Wolfram Alpha Definite Integral Calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8ab70731b1553f17c11a3bbc87e0b605)

The input in the text box under "Calculate the Integral of …" 
((1+erf((ln(y)-5)/(sqrt(2)*10)))/(1+erf((ln(4)-5)/(sqrt(2)*10))))^24 with lower limit of integration "0" and upper limit "4" under options on the right with "Integrate numerically only?" checked.

I am getting different values and hence concerned that this theoretical approximation is incorrect. Also I tried to write R code, that gives a different value from the above theoretical approximation but matches the website.

So unsure what is the real problem with the above theoretical approximation.

[R Code and Numerical Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105033/numerical-integration-of-the-power-of-the-log-normal-cumulative-distribution)

Comment: Try smaller values for the upper limit. Like .1, .5, 1.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks for this suggestion. The accuracy is better with smaller values. Though, I am unsure how to establish an accuracy level or a region of certain acceptable accuracy as a function of the parameters, $ x, \mu , \sigma, M$ which I think is necessary to understand if the above theoretical approximation is valid.